# Can't install an ActiveX Dll file on windows

Tags: c#, windows, dll

I checked all the similar topics already on the internet, but none of them helped. Maybe someone can tell me what is wrong with my installation.

I have an example_ActiveX.dll file from a client and I managed to install it via regsvr32 on my PC. I developed a software using this library and created a setup for it.

When I started to test it on other PC, I had the problem to install the DLL file. I am paying attention, that the DLL file should go into the SysWOW64 folder and I have to use the the regsvr32 command from this folder with admin permission. I still get the following error:
"The module "example_ActiveX.dll" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored ..."

I have no idea what I am missing, but I have no troubles installing and deinstalling it on my main PC.

Give me some hints here pls

Comment: Has the other PC the same OS?

Comment: There are many reasons why an ActiveX might not install or load.  Insufficient permissions is one.

Comment: Permissions, missing dependencies, wrong architecture. There are a lot of reasons. Check the Event Log after a failure and see what it says.

Comment: Both PC-s are mine and both have the same 64bit win10 freshly updated and the latest .NET. I have admin permissions on both. I did the same steps of installation. Sadly, I dont know much about its dependencies, I will try to check the Event Log, never did it tho.

Comment: So I checked the Event Log and found the following error:

The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
 and APPID 
{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
 to the user GoshaPC\Baszarab SID (S-1-5-21-3463168908-1981512364-957969616-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: After searching for this error I tried to follow these steps:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/dfc465bc-7bbd-483e-b98b-2ba56fa98313/the-applicationspecific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-launch-permission-for-the-com-server?forum=configmgrgeneral

However, I can not add the user in the Security Window, the Add and Remove buttons are grey.

https://ibb.co/cOMNs8